# Sending a for loop with pre-expanded variables over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

So I have a script that I'm working on which takes some user- and script-generated input and uses ssh to send a query to to a remote server, and redirects the output to a text file on the local server. The script has two parts, one that does this to the local server and one that needs to do the exact same thing, except over ssh. I'm having some trouble formatting this correctly. My most current attempt is as follows. The variables are all defined by the script except for $item, which is part of the for loop, and the pre-existing ones need to be expanded before being sent over ssh:

```
ssh root@"$3" "for item in $(cat /tmp/"$text_file");do "$psql" "$my_username" "$dbschema" -c "update "$5" set timestamp='now()' where "$4"='"$item"'";done"
```

To write out what I'm expecting more clearly, the following is what should be happening on the remote server, via ssh (in other words, this is what I would run if I were doing it manually on the other server without variables).

```
ssh username@hostname
    for item in $(cat /tmp/list.txt);do
       /usr/bin/psql kefka myschema -c "update important_table set timestamp='now()' where important_column='"$item"'"
    done
```

I'm trying to do this in a single ssh command because the network connection is unreliable and if I loop through dozens of individual ssh commands instead, things are going to go wrong. And using psql to connect directly to the remote database is not an option either, unfortunately.

How can I format the ssh command to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I think I'm able to create a local command that results in the desired remote command. I can write an educative answer. The problem is the desired remote command is flawed. First `for item in $(cat …);` is flawed [this way](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), then `$item` is [unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). It may be the content of `list.txt` is so specific the code never fails. Well, is it for sure? Please review the desired command. I assume the remote shell is POSIX-compliant. Is it? Is the local shell POSIX-compliant?